# text outside of the cell and table outside of the page issue

Tags: tables

I am trying to draw a table like this one :
[image]

But instead I got this

[image]

If I put a longer sentence it  just come out of the cell and the table get outside the page while I need it to respect the margin

Here is the code for the table:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\caption{Comparaison des méthodologies : convivialité}
\label{tab:conv_osstmm}
\begin{tabular}{|l|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|}
\hhline{~|--|}

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}{}}
&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{OSSTMM}}} 
&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{ISSAF}}}
&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{PTES}}}
&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{NIST S 800-115}}}
&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{OWASP}}}\\\hline

\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Structure ordonnée bla bla}} & - & + & + & + & +\\ \hline
\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Connaissances de base}} & - & + & + & - & + \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, makecell,tabularx}
    \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}
    \renewcommand{\theadgape}{}             % <-------------------
\newcommand\mcw[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textcolor{white}{\thead{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\caption{Comparaison des méthodologies : convivialité}
\label{tab:conv_osstmm}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X |*{5}{c|} }
    \hhline{~|-----|}
    \rowcolor{blue!45!black}
\multicolumn{1}{X}{\cellcolor{white}}
     &\mcw{OSSTMM} &\mcw{ISSAF} & \mcw{PTES} & \mcw{NIST S\\ 800-115} & \mcw{OWASP} \\
    \hhline{|------|}
\thead[l]{Structure\\ ordonnée bla bla}  & -- & + & + & + & + \\ 
    \hhline{|------|}
\thead[l]{Connaissances\\ de base}         & -- & + & + & -- & + \\
    \hhline{|------|}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: for my education -- is there a difference between the `thead` and `makecell` usage

Comment: @jsbibra, as far as I know, only difference is that for `thead` you can simple define specification of font used in cell. However, I must check this again in package documentation (or you can do this yourself).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{aligned-overset}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\caption{Comparaison des méthodologies : convivialité}
\label{tab:conv_osstmm}
\begin{tabular}{|l|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|}
\hhline{~|--|}

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}{}}
&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{OSSTMM}}} 
&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{ISSAF}}}
&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{PTES}}}
&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{NIST S 800-115}}}
&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{OWASP}}}\\\hline

 \textbf{\makecell[l]{here is \\ my text \\ in the cell}}& - & + & + & + & +\\ \hline
\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Connaissances de base}} & - & + & + & - & + \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. You won't see thin white lines in the colored panels (whatever PDF viewer you use).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Comparaison des méthodologies : convivialité}
\label{tab:conv_osstmm}
\begin{NiceTabular}{X[m,l]ccccc}[cell-space-limits=2pt]
& \RowStyle[color=white]{\sffamily} \Block[draw,fill=blue!45!black]{1-*}{}
  OSSTMM & ISSAF & PTES & \Block{}{NIST S\\ 800-115} & OWASP \\
\Block[hvlines]{*-*}{}
Structure ordonnée bla bla bla  & -- & + & + & +  & +  \\ 
Connaissances de base           & -- & + & + & -- & + \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]